# Sort a Map<Long, ZonedDateTime> by date in order to find max and min

Tags: java, hashmap, zoneddatetime

I have a hash map with format of **HashMap<Long, ZonedDateTime>**.
For example,

```
[(100, 01/01/2018 - 13:45:30 +0000),
 (101, 02/05/2018 - 13:45:30 +0000), 
(102, 02/01/2012 - 13:45:30 +0000)].
```

I want this output:

```
 (102, 02/01/2012 - 13:45:30 +0000)
 (100, 01/01/2018 - 13:45:30 +0000)
 (101, 02/05/2018 - 13:45:30 +0000)
```

Comment: You should be using `OffsetDateTime` class for such values, not `ZonedDateTime`. Your inputs carry an offset from UTC, not a time zone.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sort a HashMap because it always stores value in random order and provide random access.

You need to use a `LinkedHashMap` - values are inserted same as a HashMap but order is maintained in a linked list.

`LinkedHashMap` way:

1. Insert as usual.
2. Collections.sort(dateComparator)
3. Read as usual.

The next part is defining your comparator. Below is an example of a comparator which sorts a map by its values. You need to create a variation of this. Since `ZonedDateFormat` implements a compareTo method, this should ideally work as it is.

```java
Comparator dateComparator = new Comparator()   
{  
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)   
    {  
        return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) 
            (o1)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not sorted [by definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> *This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.*

But it is possible to iterate its entries and sort the output:

```java
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or convert the sorted output into `LinkedHashMap` maintaining the insertion order:

```
Map<Long. ZonedDateTime> byValue = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (v1, v2) -> v1,
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
System.out.println(byValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task is best solved without sorting at all. You just need one iteration over the `entrySet`.

```
Map.Entry<Long, ZonedDateFormat> minimum = null;
Map.Entry<Long, ZonedDateFormat> maximum = null;

for (var entry: map.entrySet()) {
  if (minimum == null || minimum.getValue().compareTo(entry.getValue()) > 0) { 
    minimum = entry;
  }
  if (maximum == null || maximum.getValue().compareTo(entry.getValue()) < 0) { 
    maximum = entry;
  } 
}
```